# JavaFX column value based on calculation

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I need to increase **amount** column's value if a product with entered barcode is already exist in the table below.
[image]

**FXML view**

```
<TableView fx:id="productTable" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="474.0" prefWidth="750.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="numberColumn" prefWidth="54.0" resizable="false" text="N#"/>
            <TableColumn prefWidth="235.0" resizable="false" text="%items.name.column">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="name"/>
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn prefWidth="189.0" resizable="false" text="%items.barCode.column">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="barcode"/>
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn prefWidth="73.0" resizable="false" text="%items.amount.column" /> // TODO: figure out how to count!
            <TableColumn prefWidth="98.0" resizable="false" text="%items.pricePerItem.column">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="price"/>
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn fx:id="totalPriceCoulmn" prefWidth="100.0" resizable="false" text="%items.totalPrice.column"/>
        </columns>
   </TableView>
```

**Product DTO**

```
public class ProductDto {

    @NotNull(message = "product.barcode.null")
    @Size(max = 13, message = "product.barcode.max.length")
    private final String barcode;

    @NotNull(message = "product.name.null")
    @Size(max = 256, message = "product.name.max.length")
    private final String name;

    @Min(value = 1, message = "product.price.min")
    private final int price;

    @JsonCreator
    public ProductDto(@JsonProperty("barcode") String barcode,
                      @JsonProperty("name") String name,
                      @JsonProperty("price") int price) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this == o) return true;
        if(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ProductDto that = (ProductDto) o;
        return Objects.equals(barcode, that.barcode);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(barcode);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductDto{" +
               "barcode='" + barcode + '\'' +
               ", name='" + name + '\'' +
               ", price=" + price +
               '}';
    }
}
```

As you can see the dto has no field amount, so the question is: is there a way to increase the amount column's value even if there is no the field in the dto (similar to **PropertyValueFactory property="?!"**)?

**Controller**

```
/**
 * @author Timur Berezhnoi.
 */
 public class MainController {
     @FXML
     private TableView<ProductDto> productTable;
     // The other code is omitted
 }
```